# Do lies about privileged conversations break the privilege?

Tags: common-law, attorney-client-privilege

It's generally the rule that communications seeking or providing legal advice are privileged if they are made in a confidential context, and that the client can erode or destroy the protection of privilege if he discloses such a communication to a third party.

But what if the client *falsely* discloses such a communication? Does the actual communication remain privileged?

Imagine a reporter approaches a lawyer because he's concerned about risks associated with publishing a story based on allegedly classified materials that have been leaked to him. The lawyer warns that the materials are in fact properly classified, and he advises the client not to publish them.

A friend bumps into the reporter on the sidewalk and asks what's going on. The reporter might say any of the following:

- "I just talked to my lawyer. He said I have a good case to sue my boss for sexual harassment."
- "I just talked to my lawyer. He said these materials are not classified."
- "I just talked to my lawyer. He said I should publish these papers."
- "I just talked to my proctologist. He said these papers are classified and I shouldn't publish them."

To what extent would any of these statements weaken the reporter's claim that his conversation with the lawyer remains privileged?

Assume that the dispute does not arise in a context where the reporter is asserting an advice-of-counsel defense. I'm open to answers from any jurisdiction, but Ohio is of special interest.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out in what context the effort to access privileged communications presents itself. In the absence of a reliance on counsel defense, how would it be legally relevant?

Comment: I can't necessarily think of anything that both is plausible and does not needlessly complicate the question. I'm just playing with the theoretical concept, so feel free to assume any scenario whose facts would not be especially material to the outcome.

Comment: So let me get this straight... "A" talks to lawyer "L" creating a client-attorney privileged conversation. "A" then lies to a random person "B" about that conversation, and you are asking if the client-attorney privilege between "A" and "L" is broken, and "L" is free to disclose anything said by "A", even if the lie is completely unrelated to the conversation?

Comment: No. I'm asking to what extent the privilege remains intact in each of the above scenarios.